# Is there any easy way to generate path reverting given commit in SVN?

Tags: svn

I need to generate patch file that **revert/undo** effects of given SVN commit (not necessary the last one). I.e. if some field was added to the class, the patch needs to remove this field, etc.

Is there any automatic way to generate this path? Or I need to prepare it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need smth like

```
svn diff -r 123:124 > your.patch
```

where 124 is the revision you want to revert.

Comment: `svn diff -c 124 > your.patch` would do the same a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me: http://blog.johang.se/2009/03/revert-commit-in-subversion.html .

Alternatively, I can use "Revert commit" option in Tortoise SVN log (which probably does the same).

Than, having commit reverted in working copy I can easily generate patch from local changes that will do just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

An invocation like `svn diff -r 124:123` would dump a patch file to the stdout which, if applied, brings the state of files as recorded in the revision `124` to the their state as recorded in the revision `123` — reversing the revisions passed to the `-r` command-line argument of `svn diff` generates a "reversed" patch.

Also note that both the conventional `patch` program and the `svn patch` command are able to apply a "normal" ("direct") patch in reverse when told to do so — they reverse the given patch themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Read `svn help diff`, note about second form of diff, `-c -M` option specially

Compare two sample diffs output

**Direct diff**

```
>svn diff -c 1264 ...
Index: Yarnet.ini
===================================================================
--- Yarnet.ini  (revision 1263)
+++ Yarnet.ini  (revision 1264)
@@ -8,5 +8,8 @@
 Image=Yarnet.bmp

 City=╨п╤А╨╛╤Б╨╗╨░╨▓╨╗╤М
+5.159.112.0-5.159.119.255
+37.1.80.0-37.1.87.255
 46.229.176.0-46.229.191.255
+185.10.128.0-185.10.131.255
 212.232.32.0-212.232.63.255
\ No newline at end of file
```

**Reverse diff**

```
>svn diff -c -1264 ...
Index: Yarnet.ini
===================================================================
--- Yarnet.ini  (revision 1264)
+++ Yarnet.ini  (revision 1263)
@@ -8,8 +8,5 @@
 Image=Yarnet.bmp

 City=╨п╤А╨╛╤Б╨╗╨░╨▓╨╗╤М
-5.159.112.0-5.159.119.255
-37.1.80.0-37.1.87.255
 46.229.176.0-46.229.191.255
-185.10.128.0-185.10.131.255
 212.232.32.0-212.232.63.255
\ No newline at end of file
```

**Short Answer**

Diff for undoing revision M is

`svn diff -c -M`